# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'PRM_ServerError' of undefined

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, deployment

I have published my code into QA server for testing. my code working fine on dev server. But on QA server my image button not fires an event. I went an developer console and see what i am getting. So i compare on my local to QA. Please find the images below. Those images from the developer tool-Console.

This is the error I am getting on QA

[image: This is the error I am getting on QA]

This is from my local host for the same page(working)

[image: This is from my local host for the same page]

**EDIT**

If image not shown. This is the error I got.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'PRM_ServerError' of undefined

MsAjaxJs?v=c42ygB2U07n37m_Sfa8ZbLGVu4Rr2gsBo7MvUEnJeZ81:1

I know this is kind of vague. But this is the error I got. I have no idea how I can find why my button not fire an event on QA server.

Please Help! Thanks

Comment: Looks like your files are not there

Comment: My images might not uploaded. I have added the error message under EDIT. Please find  @epascarello

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have resolved my issue. As my image button was not fired, I have taken out the update panel from that .aspx page and set custom error mode to off on web.config on QA server. Then I could able to see the yellow(error) page.

My error was it was connecting to the wrong login user to database. When I created a entitymodel, I hide the username and password(integrated security=True). It works perfectly at my local machine. after I published it connecting to the different login. So, I gave username and password (persist security info=True) at datasource connection string. Now my image button event fired and worked perfectly.

Finally, I put back my update panel and comment out custom error mode from web.config on published server.

I will be glad if this helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

Also had this problem with my .ascx user control (ASP.NET Web Pages project).

- Make sure you do
  [this](https://forums.asp.net/t/2121334.aspx?Uncaught+TypeError+Cannot+read+property+PRM_ParserErrorDetails+of+undefined)
  first
- In my case, I was missing a PostBackTrigger on my control:

> `<asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="yourControl" />`

Answer (score 0):

Turned out, in my case, that the session state was being lost on Login. If this issue occurs for any one on the postback of the login credentials I would investigate this avenue.

I switched my site to use SQLServer Session management and all my problems disappeared.

```
<sessionState mode="SQLServer" sqlConnectionString="ASPState" allowCustomSqlDatabase="true" cookieless="false" cookieSameSite="None" timeout="780"/>
```